# PHP DOM Get <option> Tag That Is Selected

Tags: php, dom

So let's say the HTML looks something like this:

```
<select name="some_name">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I need to extract the option tag with attribute selected="selected" from there. How can I do that? So far I have this:

```
$string = file_get_contents('test.html');

include 'htmlpurifier-4.0.0-standalone/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Strict');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$string = $purifier->purify($string);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $string);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$num = 0;

$optionTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('option');
foreach ($optionTags as $o) {
    if ($o->hasAttribute('selected')
        && 'selected' === $o->getAttribute('selected')) {
        $num = $o->nodeValue;
    }
}

echo $num;
```

And that doesn't work. The $num is still equal to zero afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it does not work because you are forgetting to access the `DOMNodeList`'s item using its property `item`.

Try this approach, loop through the entire length of the `DOMNodeList` returned. Checked if the `DOMNode` at the current item's index has an attribute named *"selected"*

```
$num = 0;
$optionTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('option');
for ($i = 0; $i < $optionTags->length; $i++ ) {
 if ($optionTags->item($i)->hasAttribute('selected') 
           && $optionTags->item($i)->getAttribute('selected') === "selected") {
     $num = $optionTags->item($i)->nodeValue;
 }
}
```

#### EDIT:

My exact code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("C:\\test.htm");
$num = 0;
$optionTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('option');
for ($i = 0; $i < $optionTags->length; $i++ ) {
  if ($optionTags->item($i)->hasAttribute('selected') 
         && $optionTags->item($i)->getAttribute('selected') === "selected") {
       $num = $optionTags->item($i)->nodeValue;
  }
}
echo "Num is " . $num;
```

Output:

Num is 3

Comment: Try with `==` instead of `===` see if that works, if not, ill run a test and see if I can get it to work

Comment: I tried that still nothing. By the way, the exact HTML is from this page: http://www.futbalvsfz.sk/sutaze/sezona-2009-2010/dospeli/5.liga-jz

Comment: When I do echo $optionTags->length; it prints 0... so that's why the loop doesn't run even once.

Comment: I would put `var_dump` to see the contents of `$string`  and `$dom`, something is not working. I haven't used `HTMLPurifier`, what is the reason for using that?

Comment: Ok I figured this out. The HTMLPurifier is stripping the whole <select> for some reason even though it seems to be valid XHTML.

Answer (score 6):

How about using **simplexml** and **XPath** selectors?

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($htmlString);
$result = $xml->xpath('//option[@selected="selected"]');

$option = array_pop($result);
var_dump($option);
```

(tested, working on PHP 5.3.0)

Answer (score 2):

More elegant code, which goes through all select boxes in html file, finds one which is needed and prints out selected option:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('somefile.html');
$sel = $dom->getElementsByTagName("select");
foreach ($sel as $select){
  if ($select->getAttribute("name") == "someselect") {//find select box with name "someselect"
    $optionTags = $select->getElementsByTagName('option');
    foreach ($optionTags as $tag){
        if ($tag->hasAttribute("selected"))
            echo $tag->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your next step in debugging is to verify that $string contains the value you expect. The original code posted is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it by doing this:

```
$xpath->query("//select[@name='foo']/option[@selected]");
```

This only returned the node which was marked as selected (it didn't have selected="selected")