# How to get some values from html data using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to pull some car make datas from the html. This is the html data where I want to get this makes.

I tried this code but it is not working.

```
<?php

$data = "<select id="c1:swfield" name="c1">
<option value="--">&gt; All Makes</option>
<option value="1167">Acura</option>
<option value="1173">Alfa Romeo</option>
<option value="1564">Smart</option>
<option value="1836">Speranza</option>
<option value="1566">Ssang Yong</option>
</select>";


preg_match_all('|<select id=\"c1:swfield\" name=\"c1\">(.*?)</select>|s', $data, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

I'm getting some empty arrays as output. As output I want to get values between option tags such as Acura, Alfa Romeo etc.

Comment: Have you tried the methods given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231231/php-dom-get-option-tag-that-is-selected

Comment: `'|<select id=\"c1:swfield\" name=\"c1\">([\s\S]*?)</select>|s'`

Comment: I need only the values between <option value=""></option>

Comment: you would find this much simpler using DOMDocument and associated methods

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of advantages to using a proper DOM parser in these sorts of cases, including knowing what data to extract.

This code uses DOMDocument and `loadHTML()` to load the data, then uses XPath to extract the data.

XPath can be difficult to start with, this uses `//select[@id="c1:swfield"]/option` which breaks down to...

- `//select` - select any `<select>` element.
- `[@id="c1:swfield"]` which has an id attribute which is `c1:swfield`.  This is how you can specify which `<select>` tag you need to extract the data from.
- `/option` - within that - extract the `<option>` elements.

This is how that code could work...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$makes = $xp->query('//select[@id="c1:swfield"]/option');
$makeList = [];
foreach ( $makes as $make ) {
    $makeList[] = $make->textContent;
}

print_r($makeList);
```

and gives (with sample data)...

```
Array
(
    [0] => > All Makes
    [1] => Acura
    [2] => Alfa Romeo
    [3] => Smart
    [4] => Speranza
    [5] => Ssang Yong
)
```

Comment: I did consider though `option[@value!="--"]`

Comment: How i can get if i need option value="this value" also ?

Comment: You could use `$make->getAttribute("value")`, so `$makeList[$make->getAttribute("value")] = $make->textContent;` would give a list indexed by the value.

Comment: Then it will be like

`foreach ( $makes as $make ) {
$makeList[$make->getAttribute("value")] = $make->textContent;
}`

Comment: Thanks Nick ! it worked.

one more doubt if i want to only one option element for a specific value how i can put ?

Comment: You could change the XPath line to something like `$makes = $xp->query('//select[@id="c1:swfield"]/option[@value="1836"]');`

Comment: Ok. great !

Here how i can set the array indexes also

makeList[$make->getAttribute("value")] = $make->textContent;

Comment: i need the array index starting 0 and then values

Comment: Suppose here i want to add the value and the element to my database then how i can

Comment: That is something completely different, if you have the data you want and not sure how to add it to the database then ask a new question (after doing some research first).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203925/discussion-between-virendra-singh-and-nigel-ren).

Answer (score 0):

You're not using quotes properly, try following code

```
    <?php

    $data = '<select id="c1:swfield" name="c1">
    <option value="--">&gt; All Makes</option>
    <option>Acura</option>
    <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option>Smart</option>
    <option>Speranza</option>
    <option>Ssang Yong</option>
    </select>';


    preg_match_all('|<select id=\"c1:swfield\" name=\"c1\">(.*?)</select>|s', $data, $matches);

    print_r($matches);

    ?>
```

Comment: i need only values of makes like Alfa Romeo

Comment: check now, hope it;ll work

Comment: i need values like Acura, Alfa Romeo, Smart.

Comment: I want to extract the values between <option value="1566">Ssang Yong</option>

Answer (score 0):

For getting the values between option tags you can use:

```
preg_match_all('|(?:<select id=\"c1:swfield\" name=\"c1\">.*?)?<option value=\".*?\">(.*?)<\/option>(?:<\/select>)?|s', $data, $matches);
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/5WSLQJ/2) is how it works.

Comment: but there is another drop down before its.

Comment: I've edited the answer to catch "all makes" option too. But at this point i too recommend using a DOM parser.